# If let expression within .iter().any

Tags: rust

Here's some code I have:

```rust
fn my_func(i: i32) -> Result<i32, String> {
    match i {
        42 => Ok(113),
        _ => Err("Can only use 42".to_string())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let myvec = [1, 2, 42];
    if myvec.iter().any(|i| my_func(*i).is_ok()) {
        println!("something was ok");
    } else {
        println!("nothing was ok");
    }
}
```

Instead of `println!("something was ok");`, I'd like to print which element was OK.

But if I assign to a variable within `any`, then it won't be visible within the `println!` statement.

Desired output, in this case, would be:

```
something was ok: 42
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Iterator::any` isn't capable of returning a value. It only returns true or false. The variant of `any` that *does* return a value is called [`Iterator::find_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find).

> Applies function to the elements of `iterator` and returns the first non-none result.
>
> `iter.find_map(f)` is equivalent to `iter.filter_map(f).next()`.

`Option<B>` is really just a Boolean with extra information in the "true" case, so we'll use that extra information to return a useful value.

```
let myvec = [1, 2, 42];
    if let Some(value) = myvec.iter().find_map(|i| my_func(*i).ok()) {
        println!("something was ok: {}", value);
    } else {
        println!("nothing was ok");
    }
}
```

[`Result::ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok) takes a `Result` and maps it to an `Option`. `Ok` becomes `Some` and any `Err` becomes `None` (with the actual error information discarded).

Answer (score 3):

Since you want the element that didn't error, use [`Iterator::find`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find) instead:

```
fn main() {
    let myvec = [1, 2, 42];
    if let Some(i) = myvec.iter().find(|&&i| my_func(i).is_ok()) {
        println!("{i} was ok"); // 42 was ok
    } else {
        println!("nothing was ok");
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4814e99c8b2efc1af243fb29f0033623)